# Why does this *ptr NOT give the actual value stored at the memory address contained in ptr variable?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, format-specifiers, conversion-specifier

Here is a basic C program about pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int variable = 20;
    int *pointerToVariable;

    pointerToVariable = &variable;

    printf("Address of variable: %x\n", &variable);
    printf("Address of variable: %x\n", pointerToVariable);
    printf("Address of variable: %x\n", *pointerToVariable); // * is the DEREFERENCING OPERATOR/INDIRECTION OPERATOR in C. 
                                                                //It gives the value stored at the memory address 
                                                                //stored in the variable which is its operand.
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Address of variable: 8ffbe4
Address of variable: 8ffbe4
Address of variable: 14
```

**But `*pointerToVariable` should print 20, shouldn't it? Because `*` gives the actual value stored at the memory address stored in its operand, right?
What am I missing?**

Comment: It does. `14` is `20` in hexadecimal

Comment: `14` is the `HEX` value of `20`.....Change `printf` format specifier to `%d` instead of `%x`.

Comment: Use %d to see expected result. As previous comments explain, %x is printing hexadecimal

Comment: OK But why did I get a downvote. All beginners make such mistakes, don't they?

Comment: @Sie it's not about the problem in the question, it is because the lack of research attempt shown by you. Please always show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: It illegal (undefined behavior) to use `%x` to print `&variable` and `pointerToVariable`. How did you come up with that idea? If you use `printf` format specifiers frivolously and without care, you will see a lot of "strange" results in the output. Spamming SO with questions about such output will usually get you downvotes. And if you made the effort to read the docs to find the proper format specifier, you'd probaly figure out by yourself why the last one prints `14`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you. I will be careful in future.

Comment: @AnT I am following [this website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) to learn. I can only read one thing at a time and I am allowed to make mistakes because I am human.

Comment: @Sie: Well, the code samples at the link are of very bad quality. And the text is far from perfect too (to put it mildly). (After reading a few pages) Sorry, this tutorial is just bad, will do some damage and will require a lot of re-learning afterwards.

Comment: @AnT Thank you very much indeed. I am going to look for another tutorial. Most probably I am going for cprogramming.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`14` is the `HEX` value of `20`.

Change `printf` format specifier to `%d` instead of `%x` to have `20` as output

```
printf("Address of variable: %d\n", *pointerToVariable);
```

Moreover correct format specifier for pointers is `%p`, so

```
printf("Address of variable: %x\n", pointerToVariable);
```

must be

```
printf("Address of variable: %p\n", (void *)pointerToVariable);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
printf("Address of variable: %x\n", &variable);
printf("Address of variable: %x\n", pointerToVariable);
```

are wrong, because you used wrong format specifier which  causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To print an address, you need to

- use `%p` format specifier
- cast the corresponding argument to `(void *)`

Then, for

```
printf("Address of variable: %x\n", *pointerToVariable);
```

statement, the `%x` format specifier prints the hexadecimal representation of the supplied integer value, so you've got the correct output there.

Answer (score 1):

Your  formatting is hex (base 16) (%x) this line : 
 `printf("Address of variable: %x\n", *pointerToVariable);`// output: 14

If you want the output in base 10, then you need to provide the right formatting :

```
 printf("Address of variable: %d\n", *pointerToVariable); // output : 20

// 1*16 + 4 = 20
```

Good luck